# Android Device not recognised by win7 virtualbox

Tags: android, windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04

I am running a VirtualBox with Windows 7 on it in Ubuntu 11.04. I want to use this environment for Android development.

I followed the setup instructions and can debug on the emulator. I have used the VirtualBox settings to set up a USB filter for my phone(LG Ally). When I connect the phone, the filter appears to be working since I don't see it in Ubuntu and Windows does recognize that something is attached.

When i try to update the drivers using the ones downloaded with the SDK, Windows says that the drivers are up to date. Device Manager does not show the device name, referring to is as USB Composite Device.

If explorer is opened, my phone does not show up. It also does not show up when attempting to debug on the device(through eclipse).

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to force update the driver using the SDK one.

1. Open Device Manager
2. Find USB device
3. Right click, Update Driver Software
4. Browse my computer for driver software
5. Find SDK USB drivers

Alternatively, try removing the USB composite device from the device manager, then reboot the Windows machine. Connect the phone, make sure the Windows system has exclusive control, then start the Windows system again. When the device manager picks up the new hardware, tell it to use the driver from the SDK.

Hope that helps

-Jun

Comment: I wasn't able to get either method to work, actually somehow the second method ended up preventing windows from starting and I had to jump back to an earlier config lmao.

thanks for trying to help tho!